# How do I add Headers in List of Tables page?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I'm new to LaTex, so please bear with me if this is a newbie question. I am using a template where `\listoftables` is defined as follows:

```
\def\listoftables{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \fi\chapter*{List of Tables\@mkboth
   {LIST OF TABLES}{LIST OF TABLES}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}\@starttoc{lot}\if@restonecol
  \twocolumn\fi}
```

When I add `\listoftables` to my document, I get something like this:

[image: Current view of the list of tables section]

What I'd like to add is something like this:

[image]

**How do I add the header row at the top for each column in the list of tables**? Thank you in advanced for your answers and suggestions!

Comment: This deliberately depends on the underlying class

Comment: thank you this code is really helpful for me. I want to do same for the List of Figures as well as for the Content List. please give me hints on where to change so I can get desired output. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A version for the `book.cls`, with some tricky statements written to the `.lot` file

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{tocloft}


\makeatletter
\newlength{\latexpnumwidth}
\setlength{\latexpnumwidth}{\@pnumwidth}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\textbf{\tablename}~}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{25pt}
\let\origcftdot\cftdot
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\cftsetpnumwidth{25pt}}

\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftdot}{}} % Remove the dots
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{table}{\numberline{\textbf{\tablename}~}\textbf{Title}}{\textbf{Page}}} % Write the header line
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftdot}{\origcftdot}}% Can be written 'expanded' and enable the dots again
\addtocontents{lot}{\vskip0.5\baselineskip\par}% Some vertical spacing 
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\listoftables

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{table}
\caption{Foo stuff table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update with `Table` prefix removed.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{tocloft}


\makeatletter
\newlength{\latexpnumwidth}
\setlength{\latexpnumwidth}{\@pnumwidth}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{25pt}
\let\origcftdot\cftdot
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\cftsetpnumwidth{25pt}}

\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftdot}{}} % Remove the dots
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{table}{\numberline{\textbf{\tablename}~}\textbf{Title}}{\textbf{Page}}} % Write the header line
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftdot}{\origcftdot}}% Can be written 'expanded' and enable the dots again
\addtocontents{lot}{\vskip0.5\baselineskip\par}% Some vertical spacing 
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\listoftables

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{table}
\caption{Foo stuff table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I voted +1, also I deliberately think, that you supported typographical nonsense.  Your a magician. :-)

Comment: @Jan: :D :D :D ... thanks. Let's call it 'code golfing' :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you! It now looks very close [ http://imgur.com/a/kZhl2 ]. However, the dots won't go away in my case and the "Table" and "Title" headers are a bit too close to each other. As a newbie, I wonder why that might be the case. Could that be because the `\def` of `\listoftables` in my `.sty` file is blocking some formatting commands later? If you have any suggestion, please let me know. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually...please disregard my comment above. Once I included `\usepackage{tocloft}`, it works. However, I'd like to know how to remove `Table` prefix in front of each row (as @Jan correctly pointed out, it's redundant and is a typographically ugly), and how to adjust the alignment of (the horizontal distance between) `Table`, `Title` and `Page` headers now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user1330974: Change the `\cfttabnumwidth` and the `\cftsetpnumwidth` more to your needs to increase the spacing. I've removed the `Table` prefix.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you very much for the suggestion! I have posted an "answer" below as follow-up questions. Could you please take a look and help?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the Comment box is not long enough, to put in all my questions and comments.  So I put it in this answer box.  I beg your pardon, if it doesn't help you.

I am not sure, to understand your exact problem.

You say, you have to use a LaTeX-style (you named es "template")of your department has created. Is the presented code taken from that template?

If so, I'd say, that the style is up to the recommendations of your department.

If you are using it, nobody should complain about the wrong layout.

For example: I am sure, you don't have to add the words "Example of" to the List of Tables, do you?  Therefore I guess, that this is a mere, abstract example, which has not to be copied literally.

I think, the first red box, you painted in that image, is an abstract example given to you.  I am convinced you don't have to copy it literally.  At least, it describes the function, each column has.  But this is trivial and hence not worth mentioning.  If it wasn't trivial, you have to add similar headers also to the Table of Contents, List of Figures, etc.  That would read strange, wouldn't it?

Even more, I think, that adding the word "Table" in front of each line adds zero (NOTHING) usefull information to this line of entry.  Honestly: what do you expect a table, labeled "List of Tables" to contain?  If you don't want to fool your gentle readers, it will contain nothing else than a list of tables contained in this document.  The repetition of that useless word will make the reader sleepy, and that is contra!

Regarding your example, you should make usage of the optional `[]` braces in the `\caption`-command, to insert a somewhat shorter table title.  If you do so, the content in the braces will be inserted in the List of Tables section.  In full length you should type:

```
\caption[Common challenges that high school students face]{Common challenges, that high school students face, which we collected from student participatory design workgroup}
```

So my short answer is: use that style/template you are given.  It works perfectly and gives suitable results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question because it seems confusing. Please review it and let me know if you could show me a way to add column headers in List of Tables in LaTeX. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Christian's answer and comments above, I have got it very close to working as shown in the code and image below, but I notice that

```
%%%% This is in the main tex file %%%%
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{urcs-thesis}
%\linespread{1}  % Use 1.2 for final version

% Add bibliograph to TOC
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

% Allow \includegraphics[scale=•]{•}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[font={small, it}]{caption}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Change spacing for chapter headings 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}

% Add numbers/TOC entries for subsubparagraphs
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% my hack
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % for appendix
\usepackage{color}
\def\bsq#1{%both single quotes
\lq{#1}\rq}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % to strike the underline in journal titles
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float} % for forcing figure placement
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rchi}{{\mathpalette\irchi\relax}} % to raise chi symbol above the line
\newcommand{\irchi}[2]{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1\chi$}} % inner command, used by \rchi
\usepackage{array}  % to align left inside table http://texblog.org/2008/05/07/fwd-equal-cell-width-right-and-centre-aligned-content/
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{
>{\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\latexpnumwidth}
\setlength{\latexpnumwidth}{\@pnumwidth}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{0.3in}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\cftsetpnumwidth{0.5in}}
\let\origcftdot\cftdot

\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftdot}{}} % Remove the dots
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{table}{\numberline{\textbf{\tablename}~}\textbf{Title}}{\textbf{Page}}} % Write the header line
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftdot}{\origcftdot}}% Can be written 'expanded' and enable the dots again
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Thesis title}
\author{Author Name}%$^\ast$}
\thesissupervisor{Professor X^\ast$ and Professor Y$^\dagger$}
\maketitle


\tableofcontents
\include{abstract}

\listoftables
\listoffigures
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{introduction}
\end{document}
%%%% End of the main tex file %%%%

%%%% This is in a separate file called 'introduction.tex' %%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}
Hello World!
%%%% End of 'introduction.tex'%%%%%

%%%% This is in a separate file called 'urcs-thesis.sty' %%%%
\typeout{Document Style `urcsthesis' <14 April 1993> (modified).}
%
% margin settings
%
\textwidth 6.00in
\textheight 8.5in
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\headheight 12pt
\headsep 30pt
\footskip 30pt
%
% paragraph settings
%
\parskip 4pt plus 1.5pt minus 1.5pt
\clubpenalty 500
\widowpenalty 500
\displaywidowpenalty=500
%
% more spacing between text and footnote
%
\def\footnoterule{\kern 2pt% extra space
\kern-3\p@\hrule width .4\columnwidth\kern 2.6\p@}
\footnotesep 10pt % more space between footnotes

%
% These changes to the defaults set in urcsmargin.sty are necessary to
% make the page number come out as requred by the thesis manual.
%
%\topmargin -.5in
%\headheight 12pt
%\headsep 42pt
%
% get UR macros
%
\newlength{\chaptitlewidth}
\newlength{\chapnowidth}
\input{urcsmacros}
%
% Space and a half.  Required because the committee designing the
% standards was confused.  Cannot be changed because it is a rule.
% (NGM)
%   
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\singlespacethesis}{\def\baselinestretch{1}}
%
% year date format.  Required by new manual 1992
%
\dateY
%
% thesisby
%
\def\thesisby#1{\gdef\@thesisby{#1}}
\def\@thesisby{\vskip 1ex by\vskip 1ex}
%
% thesissubmit
%
\def\thesissubmit#1{\gdef\@thesissubmit{#1}}
\def\@thesissubmit{\vskip 5ex Submitted in Partial Fulfillment of the\\~\\
Requirements for the Degree\vskip 1ex}
%
% thesisproposal
%
\def\thesisproposal{\thesissubmit{\vskip 5ex
Thesis\\~\\for the Degree\vskip 1ex}}
%
% thesisdegree
%
\def\thesisdegree#1{\gdef\@thesisdegree{#1}}
\def\@thesisdegree{{Degree name here}}
%
% thesissupervisor.  Changed 1992
%
\def\thesissupervisor#1{\gdef\@thesissupervisor{#1}}
\def\@thesissupervisor{UNKNOWN}
%
% thesissupervise
%
\def\thesissupervise#1{\gdef\@thesissupervise{#1}} 
\def\@thesissupervise{\vskip 5ex Supervised by\\~\\
  \@thesissupervisor\vskip 1ex}
%
% thesisdepartment  Changed 1992
%
%
\def\thesisdepartmentone#1{\gdef\@thesisdepartmentone{#1}}
\def\@thesisdepartmentone{$^\ast$ Department Name\\
School of Engineering \& Applied Sciences}

\def\thesisdepartmenttwo#1{\gdef\@thesisdepartmenttwo{#1}}
\def\@thesisdepartmenttwo{$^\dagger$ Department Name\\School Name}

% thesisuniversity  Changed 1992 (NGM)
%
\def\thesisuniversity#1{\gdef\@thesisuniversity{#1}}
\def\@thesisuniversity{
\\University Name\\City, State\\}

%
% redefine maketitle to use the empty page style
%
\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
 \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
 \def\@makefnmark{\hbox
   to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
 \newpage
   \global\@topnum\z@        % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
   \@maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax
 \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
%
% redefine @maketitle to box the information appropriately
%   added parbox and hskip before it
%   added techrepdept and techrepnum
%   changed vertical space after date
%
\def\@maketitle{
  %
  % Turn off space and a half for title page (NGM)
  %
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}        % So we get no page number on the title page
  \null
  \vspace{0.25in}              % Vertical space above title.
  \begin{center}
    {\huge \@title \par}        % Title set in \huge size.
    {\large \@thesisby          % Author set in \large size
      \@author \par}
    {\large \@thesissubmit \@thesisdegree}
    {\large \@thesissupervise}
    {\large \@thesisdepartmentone \vskip 0.5em}
    {\large \@thesisdepartmenttwo \vskip 1.5em}
    {\large \@thesisuniversity \vskip 1.5em \@date}
  \end{center}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \clearpage
}
%
% curriculumvitaehead
%
\def\curriculumvitaehead#1{\gdef\@curriculumvitaehead{#1}}
\def\@curriculumvitaehead{\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{Biographical Sketch\@mkboth{BIOGRAPHICAL SKETCH}{BIOGRAPHICAL SKETCH}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Biographical Sketch}}
%
% curriculumvitae
%
\newenvironment{curriculumvitae}{\@curriculumvitaehead}{\clearpage}
%
% acknowledgmentshead
%
\def\acknowledgmentshead#1{\gdef\@acknowledgmentshead{#1}}
\def\@acknowledgmentshead{\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{Acknowledgments\@mkboth{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}}
%
% acknowledgments
%
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}{\@acknowledgmentshead}{\clearpage}
%
% abstracthead
%
\def\abstracthead#1{\gdef\@abstracthead{#1}}
\def\@abstracthead{\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{Abstract\@mkboth{ABSTRACT}{ABSTRACT}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}}
%
% use narrow text width for abstract to center under window
% vfil before abstract
%
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\@abstracthead}{\clearpage}
%
% contributorsandfundinghead
%
\def\contributorsandfundinghead#1{\gdef\@contributorsandfundinghead{#1}}
\def\@contributorsandfundinghead{\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{Contributors and Funding Sources\@mkboth{CONTRIBUTORS AND FUNDING
SOURCES}{CONTRIBUTORS AND FUNDING SOURCES}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contributors and Funding Sources}}
%
% contributors and funding
%
\newenvironment{contributorsandfunding}{\@contributorsandfundinghead}{\clearpage}
%
% count chapters and sections two levels deep
%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
%
% enter only chapters and top sections are in the table of contents
%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%
% redefine plain page to put page numbers towards outside.
%
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
\def\@oddhead{\rm\hfil\thepage}\def\@oddfoot{}%
\def\@evenhead{\rm\thepage\hfil}\def\@evenfoot{}}
\pagestyle{plain}
%
% chapter redefinitions
%
\def\@chapapp{Chapter}
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\firstchapter{0} % for starting page numbers in arabic
%
% \@makechapterhead {TEXT} : Makes the heading for the \chapter command.
%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{     % Heading for \chapter command
  \cleardoublepage
  \ifcase\firstchapter
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \def\firstchapter{1} % do not do this again
  \fi
  \vspace*{50pt}             % Space at top of text page.
  { \parindent 0pt \raggedright
    \par
    % Print chapter number and title.
    \huge\bf\thechapter\hspace{1em}%
\settowidth{\chapnowidth}{\huge\bf\thechapter\hspace{1em}}%
\setlength{\chaptitlewidth}{\textwidth}%
\addtolength{\chaptitlewidth}{-\chapnowidth}%
\parbox[t]{\chaptitlewidth}{\raggedright#1}
  \nobreak                   % TeX penalty to prevent page break.
  \vskip 40pt                % Space between title and text.
  }
}
%
% \tableofcontents gets the title changed
%
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \fi\chapter*{Table of Contents\@mkboth{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
  \@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
%
% \listoffigures gets table of contents entry
%
\def\listoffigures{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \fi\chapter*{List of Figures\@mkboth
   {LIST OF FIGURES}{LIST OF FIGURES}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}\@starttoc{lof}\if@restonecol
    \twocolumn\fi}
%
% \listoffigures gets table of contents entry
%
\def\listoftables{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \fi\chapter*{List of Tables\@mkboth
   {LIST OF TABLES}{LIST OF TABLES}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}\@starttoc{lot}\if@restonecol
  \twocolumn\fi}
%
% \@makeschapterhead {TEXT} : Makes the heading for the \chapter* command.
%
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{    % Heading for \chapter* command
  \vspace*{50pt}             % Space at top of page.
  \begin{center}
  {\huge #1} % Print title.
  \end{center}
  \nobreak                   % TeX penalty to prevent page break.
  \vskip 40pt                % Space between title and text.
  }
%
% place bibliography in table of contents
%
\def\thebibliography#1{\cleardoublepage\chapter*{Bibliography\@mkboth
  {BIBLIOGRAPHY}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}\list
  {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
%
% \clearpage added to start of appendicies
%
\def\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \def\@chapapp{Appendix}
  \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}
%%%% End of 'urcs-thesis.sty' %%%%

%%%% This is in a separate file called 'urcsmacros.tex' %%%%
%
% urcsmacros
%
% author: Lawrence A. Crowl
% last updated: 28 April 1990
%
% BibTeX
%
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{{B\kern-.0833em{\sc ib}\kern-.1667em%
T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
%
% SLiTeX
%
\newcommand{\SliTeX}{{\rm S\kern-.06em{\sc l\kern-.035emi}\kern-.06em
T\kern -.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
%
% UNIX
%
\newcommand{\UNIX}{{\sc Unix}}
%
% trademark
%
\newcommand{\trademark}{$^{\rm TM}$}
%
% singlespacing (for use in doublespaced documents)
%
\def\doublespacefactor#1#2{%
\newenvironment{singlespace}{\baselineskip #2\baselineskip}%
{\par \baselineskip #1\baselineskip}%
\par \baselineskip #1\baselineskip}
%
% various latin abbreviations
%
\def\adhoc{{\em ad hoc}}
\def\aposteriori{{\em a posteriori}}
\def\apriori{{\em a priori}}
\def\Cf{{\em Cf.}}
\def\cf{{\em cf.}}
\def\Eg{{\em E.g.}}
\def\eg{{\em e.g.}}
\def\etal{{et al.}}
\def\etc{{etc.\ }}
\def\Ibid{{\em Ibid.}}
\def\ibid{{\em ibid.}}
\def\Id{{\em Id.}}
\def\id{{\em id.}}
\def\Ie{{\em I.e.}}
\def\ie{{\em i.e.}}
\def\Loccit{{\em Loc.\ cit.}}
\def\loccit{{\em loc.\ cit.}}
\def\Opcit{{\em Op.\ cit.}}
\def\opcit{{\em op.\ cit.}}
\def\qv{{\em q.v.}}
\def\Qv{{\em Q.v.}}
\def\viz{{\em viz.}}
%
% andbreak  (for breaking author lists)
%
\def\andbreak{%% \begin{tabular}
\end{tabular}\\\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%% \end{tabular}
}
%
% titlequote
%
\def\titlequote#1{\hfill
\parbox{4in}{\begin{flushright}{\small\it #1}\end{flushright}}}
%
% weekdaystring
%
% Dump the day of the week in string form.
% This macro is only valid from 1901 A.D. through 2099 A.D.
%
\def\weekdaystring#1#2#3{{% extra brace saves enclosing register state
%
% days through the end of the year
% days := current year * 365
\count10=#3%
\multiply\count10 by 365%
% leap years := year / 4
\count11=#3%
\divide\count11 by 4%
% days := days + leap years
\advance\count10 by \count11
%
% find out if the current year is a leap year
% last leap year := leap years * 4
\count12=\count11%
\multiply\count12 by 4
% years since last leap year := current year - last leap year
\count13=#3%
\advance\count13 by -\count12%
% years since last leap year equals zero when current year is a leap year
%
% subtract off those days in this month and the following months
% days = days - following days [ is leap ] [ current month ]
\ifcase#2%
\or\ifcase\count13\advance\count10 by -366% leap January
\else\advance\count10 by -365% normal January
\fi%
\or\ifcase\count13\advance\count10 by -335% leap February
\else\advance\count10 by -334% normal February
\fi%
\or\advance\count10 by -306% March
\or\advance\count10 by -275% April
\or\advance\count10 by -245% May
\or\advance\count10 by -214% June
\or\advance\count10 by -184% July
\or\advance\count10 by -153% August
\or\advance\count10 by -122% September
\or\advance\count10 by -92% October
\or\advance\count10 by -61% November
\or\advance\count10 by -31% December
\fi%
%
% update days by day of month
% days := days + current day
\advance\count10 by #1%
%
% find weekday number
% offset for initial day of the week
\advance\count10 by 5
% last monday := (current day / 7) * 7
\count14=\count10%
\divide\count14 by 7%
\multiply\count14 by 7
% weekday number := current day - last monday
\count15=\count10%
\advance\count15 by -\count14
%
% now dump out appropriate string
\ifcase\count15 Monday\or Tuesday\or Wednesday%
\or Thursday\or Friday\or Saturday\or Sunday\fi%
}}
%
% monthstring
%
% Dump the month in string form.
%
\def\monthstring#1{\ifcase#1\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May%
\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi}
%
% dateWDMY
%
% Redefine \today as "weekdaystring daynumber monthstring yearnumber" format.
%
\def\dateWDMY{\def\today{\weekdaystring{\day}{\month}{\year}\space%
\number\day\space\monthstring{\month}\space\number\year}}
%
% dateDMY
%
% Redefine \today as "daynumber monthstring yearnumber" format.
%
\def\dateDMY{\def\today{\number\day\space\monthstring{\month}%
\space\number\year}}
%
% dateWMDY
%
% Redefine \today as "weekdaystring monthstring daynumber, yearnumber" format.
%
\def\dateWMDY{\def\today{\weekdaystring{\day}{\month}{\year}\space%
\monthstring{\month}\space\number\day,\space\number\year}}
%
% dateMDY
%
% Redefine \today as "monthstring daynumber, yearnumber" format.
%
\def\dateMDY{\def\today{\monthstring{\month}\space\number\day,%
\space\number\year}}
%
% dateMY
%
% Redefine \today as "monthstring yearnumber" format.
%
\def\dateMY{\def\today{\monthstring{\month}\space\number\year}}
%
% dateY
%
% Redefine \today as "yearnumber" format.
%
\def\dateY{\def\today{\number\year}}
%%%% End of 'urcsmacros.tex' %%%%
```

1) there is a trailing "dot" at the end of the column header row (how do I remove that?)

2) I cannot turn on the "dots" back again in the table row (probably I do not understand what Christian's comment, "Can be writter 'epxanded' and enable the dots again", mean

Anyone (including Christian) please suggest an answer and I'll update this post as necessary for other users if they try to accomplish what I am trying to do here. Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Well, you should have posted the code actually. Follow-up - questions are no answers, so it is very likely that somebody else will flag this as non-answer (not me, in this case)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for not flagging it. :) I have included the code as well and hopefully, it'll now be a legitimate "answer". Please let me know how I might be able to remove the trailing "dot" and turn the "dots" back on after the header row correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Your code neither has a `\documentclass` nor reveals what is inside `introduction` or `abstract`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you so much for being patient with me. I'm relatively new to TeX. I added more code (things that I think are related) to give you a better picture of what might be wrong. Please let me know if I missed anything. Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, I think `titlesec` is the issue. `tocloft` and `titlesec/titletoc` should not be combined. There's nothing I can do here for you

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you so much for your help so far! I guess I'll just have to give up on this now because the `titlesec` package is already in the thesis template and I shouldn't mess with it unless I know what I'm doing. :)