# Adding "Page" heading on righthand number column of ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a thesis that has a table of contents with the following codes at the beginning of my file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=2in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{\normalsize \normalfont TABLE OF CONTENTS}}%
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Begins Codes for TOC 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%End of Codes for TOC
```

Everything works great for the table of contents except that the my school wants me to add the "Page" heading atop the page numbers' heading on the right-hand side, which would look like this:

[image]

Any idea to tweak my code? If I have a choice, I prefer not to replace the entire codes because I do not want to start all over again from zero. I am a good user of ShareLatex but I do not consider myself as an expert. Let me know if you need to see additional codes. Thank you very much for your time and helping hands.

Comment: Please provide a compilable code.

Comment: See also the possible answers here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346280/how-do-i-add-headers-in-list-of-tables-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the document or in the preamble, add the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\hspace*{\fill}Page\par}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=2in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{\normalsize \normalfont TABLE OF CONTENTS}}%
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Begins Codes for TOC 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%End of Codes for TOC
\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\par\hspace*{\fill}Page\par}
\tableofcontents
\section{Some section}
\end{document}
```