# List of figures with three Sub-headings in Thesis using documentclass "Report"

Tags: tocloft

How can I customize the Latex to make list of figures in format shown in figure.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\include{listofsymbols}
\end{document}
```

[image: REQUIRED FORMAT]

Comment: Related: [How do I add Headers in List of Tables page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346301/134144)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this will do for you.

```
% lofprob.tex SE 524226 column headers in LoF
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% center the caption texts
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnumb}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
% Add the column headers
\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Figure} \hfill \textbf{Caption} \hfill 
  \textbf{Page}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Number} \hfill \textbf{Number}\par}
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{Watermark on the bank currency note (12)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{Various classifications of watermarking}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{Image watermark embedding scheme}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```